Rspec on Docker with database_cleaner causes remote URL error: RemoteDatabaseUrl
I'm working in Docker, trying to run bundle exec rspec ./spec/services/something/something_spec.rb and I am getting this error
DatabaseCleaner::Safeguard::Error::RemoteDatabaseUrl:
ENV['DATABASE_URL'] is set to a remote URL

Tried a couple of thing but so far nothing was helping

I'm working on Docker, trying to run bundle exec rspec — you should run tests inside the docker, don't need to install dependencies on local machine, that's idea of the docker

Command was being run inside of docker, if that wasn't clear enough

My initial around was to just temporarily comment out DatabaseCleaner use in spec/rails_helper.rb so I could run the test locally in development environment but that wasn't great.
Then I after reading for a while I found a better solution, tried this
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.allow_remote_database_url = true
  end

And it worked. Hope that helps!

While answering you own question can be a useful way to share knowledge the question still has to answerable and the answer should be generally applicable (and preferably a good practice) and not just "I thought the error was annoying so I silenced it". Worst case this could be something like that you're wiping your production database! We still know nothing here about why your setup is using a remote url and not connecting for example via a local socket.
